# Taking the power of a series gives a terribly complicated expression

Tags: series-expansion

I have a series 
$$\Phi_2=\sum_{0\leq n\leq N}a_nq^n+O(q)^{N+1}$$
 whose coefficients $a_n$ are Laurent polynomials in the variables $X_1,X_2$.

I want to find $\Phi^3$. This is should be pretty simple as it is just adding some of the $a_n$ polynomials. However Mathematica is returning a series whose coefficients are rational functions. Upon using `Simplify` it returns the good result with polynomials as coefficient.

This is quite puzzling to me and as this is in the middle of a big calculation using `Simplify` in every step takes a very long time. I'd like to know why are these rational function appearing to use `Simplify` only when strictly necessary.

Here is the actual function. Sorry for the huge expression but I couldn't find a smaller example for which I get the same mistake

```
In[140]:= Φ2

Out[140]= SeriesData[q, 0, {
 Complex[0, -6] Pi + Complex[0, 1] Pi/X[
   1] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1] + Complex[0, 1] Pi/X[
   2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1]/X[
   2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1]^(-1) X[2], 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  Complex[0, -54] Pi + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1]^(-2) + Complex[0, 14]
     Pi/X[1] + Complex[0, 14] Pi X[1] + Complex[0, 1]
     Pi X[1]^2 + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[2]^(-2) + Complex[0, -6] Pi X[1]
     X[2]^(-2) + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1]^2 X[2]^(-2) + Complex[0, 14]
     Pi/X[2] + Complex[0, -6] Pi X[1]^(-1)/X[
   2] + Complex[0, 14] Pi X[1]/X[2] + Complex[0, -6] Pi X[1]^2/X[
   2] + Complex[0, 14] Pi X[2] + Complex[0, -6] Pi X[1]^(-2) X[
    2] + Complex[0, 14] Pi X[1]^(-1) X[2] + Complex[0, -6] Pi X[1] X[
    2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[2]^2 + Complex[0, 1]
     Pi X[1]^(-2) X[2]^2 + Complex[0, -6] Pi X[1]^(-1) X[2]^2, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  Complex[0, -324] Pi + Complex[0, 14] Pi X[1]^(-2) + Complex[0, 92]
     Pi/X[1] + Complex[0, 92] Pi X[1] + Complex[0, 14]
     Pi X[1]^2 + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1] X[2]^(-3) + Complex[0, 1]
     Pi X[1]^2 X[2]^(-3) + Complex[0, 14] Pi X[2]^(-2) + Complex[0, 1]
     Pi X[1]^(-1) X[2]^(-2) + Complex[0, -54] Pi X[1]
     X[2]^(-2) + Complex[0, 14] Pi X[1]^2 X[2]^(-2) + Complex[0, 1]
     Pi X[1]^3 X[2]^(-2) + Complex[0, 92] Pi/X[
   2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1]^(-2)/X[
   2] + Complex[0, -54] Pi X[1]^(-1)/X[2] + Complex[0, 92] Pi X[1]/X[
   2] + Complex[0, -54] Pi X[1]^2/X[2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1]^3/X[
   2] + Complex[0, 92] Pi X[2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1]^(-3) X[
    2] + Complex[0, -54] Pi X[1]^(-2) X[2] + Complex[0, 92]
     Pi X[1]^(-1) X[2] + Complex[0, -54] Pi X[1] X[2] + Complex[0, 1]
     Pi X[1]^2 X[2] + Complex[0, 14] Pi X[2]^2 + Complex[0, 1]
     Pi X[1]^(-3) X[2]^2 + Complex[0, 14]
     Pi X[1]^(-2) X[2]^2 + Complex[0, -54]
     Pi X[1]^(-1) X[2]^2 + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1] X[2]^2 + Complex[
    0, 1] Pi X[1]^(-2) X[2]^3 + Complex[0, 1]
     Pi X[1]^(-1) X[2]^3}, 0, 72, 24]

In[141]:= Φ2^3

Out[141]= SeriesData[q, 0, {(
   Complex[0, -6] Pi + Complex[0, 1] Pi/X[
    1] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1] + Complex[0, 1] Pi/X[
    2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1]/X[
    2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1]^(-1) X[2])^3, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   3 (Complex[0, -6] Pi + Complex[0, 1] Pi/X[
     1] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1] + Complex[0, 1] Pi/X[
     2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1]/X[
     2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1]^(-1) X[2])^2 (
   Complex[0, -54] Pi + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1]^(-2) + Complex[0, 14]
      Pi/X[1] + Complex[0, 14] Pi X[1] + Complex[0, 1]
      Pi X[1]^2 + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[2]^(-2) + Complex[0, -6] Pi X[1]
      X[2]^(-2) + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1]^2 X[2]^(-2) + Complex[0, 14]
      Pi/X[2] + Complex[0, -6] Pi X[1]^(-1)/X[
    2] + Complex[0, 14] Pi X[1]/X[2] + Complex[0, -6] Pi X[1]^2/X[
    2] + Complex[0, 14] Pi X[2] + Complex[0, -6] Pi X[1]^(-2) X[
     2] + Complex[0, 14] Pi X[1]^(-1) X[2] + Complex[0, -6] Pi X[1] X[
     2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[2]^2 + Complex[0, 1]
      Pi X[1]^(-2) X[2]^2 + Complex[0, -6] Pi X[1]^(-1) X[2]^2), 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, (Complex[0, -6] Pi + Complex[0, 1] Pi/X[
     1] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1] + Complex[0, 1] Pi/X[
     2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1]/X[
     2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1]^(-1) X[2])^3 (
   3 (Complex[0, -6] Pi + Complex[0, 1] Pi/X[
       1] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1] + Complex[0, 1] Pi/X[
       2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1]/X[
       2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1]^(-1) X[
        2])^(-2) (
      Complex[0, -54] Pi + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1]^(-2) + Complex[0, 14]
         Pi/X[1] + Complex[0, 14] Pi X[1] + Complex[0, 1]
         Pi X[1]^2 + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[2]^(-2) + Complex[0, -6] Pi X[
        1] X[2]^(-2) + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1]^2 X[2]^(-2) + Complex[
        0, 14] Pi/X[2] + Complex[0, -6] Pi X[1]^(-1)/X[
       2] + Complex[0, 14] Pi X[1]/X[2] + Complex[0, -6] Pi X[1]^2/X[
       2] + Complex[0, 14] Pi X[2] + Complex[0, -6] Pi X[1]^(-2) X[
        2] + Complex[0, 14] Pi X[1]^(-1) X[2] + Complex[0, -6] Pi X[1]
         X[2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[2]^2 + Complex[0, 1]
         Pi X[1]^(-2) X[2]^2 + Complex[0, -6]
         Pi X[1]^(-1) X[2]^2)^2 + 3 (
      Complex[0, -6] Pi + Complex[0, 1] Pi/X[
       1] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1] + Complex[0, 1] Pi/X[
       2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1]/X[
       2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1]^(-1) X[
        2])^(-1) (
     Complex[0, -324] Pi + Complex[0, 14] Pi X[1]^(-2) + Complex[
       0, 92] Pi/X[
      1] + Complex[0, 92] Pi X[1] + Complex[0, 14]
        Pi X[1]^2 + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1] X[2]^(-3) + Complex[0, 1]
        Pi X[1]^2 X[2]^(-3) + Complex[0, 14] Pi X[2]^(-2) + Complex[
       0, 1] Pi X[1]^(-1) X[2]^(-2) + Complex[0, -54] Pi X[1]
        X[2]^(-2) + Complex[0, 14] Pi X[1]^2 X[2]^(-2) + Complex[0, 1]
        Pi X[1]^3 X[2]^(-2) + Complex[0, 92] Pi/X[
      2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1]^(-2)/X[
      2] + Complex[0, -54] Pi X[1]^(-1)/X[
      2] + Complex[0, 92] Pi X[1]/X[2] + Complex[0, -54] Pi X[1]^2/X[
      2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1]^3/X[
      2] + Complex[0, 92] Pi X[2] + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1]^(-3) X[
       2] + Complex[0, -54] Pi X[1]^(-2) X[2] + Complex[0, 92]
        Pi X[1]^(-1) X[2] + Complex[0, -54] Pi X[1] X[2] + Complex[
       0, 1] Pi X[1]^2 X[2] + Complex[0, 14] Pi X[2]^2 + Complex[0, 1]
        Pi X[1]^(-3) X[2]^2 + Complex[0, 14]
        Pi X[1]^(-2) X[2]^2 + Complex[0, -54]
        Pi X[1]^(-1) X[2]^2 + Complex[0, 1] Pi X[1] X[2]^2 + Complex[
       0, 1] Pi X[1]^(-2) X[2]^3 + Complex[0, 1]
        Pi X[1]^(-1) X[2]^3))}, 0, 72, 24]
```

I tried with Mathematica 11.2 and 12 and I get the same mistake.

Comment: I haven't looked at your problem specifically, but you may find that `Expand` (for example) gives the same result as `Simplify`, but much faster.

Comment: Nope 'Expand' doesn't get rid of the undesired denominators. It just gives each term separate. I still get a sum of rational functions instead of a polynomial.

Comment: `Map[Factor, Φ2^3]` shows there are denominators anyway (monomials `X[1]^k X[2]^k`, as in the answer below)

Comment: Hi I didn't expected a comment so much time after. The point is not that I get something in the denominator as below, the problem is that I get a rational function (with sums in the denominator) $\frac{\dots +\dots +\dots}{\dots +\dots +\dots}$ This is what is puzzling me. At the end I decided to use the solution below but I am still confused on why do I get some big expression in the denominator

Answer (score 3):

You could try using cubing the normal version, and then converting back to a series:

```
Normal[Φ2]^3 + O[q]^3 //TeXForm
```

> $-\frac{i \left(\pi  X(2) X(1)^2+\pi  X(1)^2+\pi  X(2)^2 X(1)-6 \pi  X(2) X(1)+\pi  X(1)+\pi  X(2)^2+\pi 
>    X(2)\right)^3}{X(1)^3 X(2)^3}-\frac{3 i \pi ^3 q \left(X(2) X(1)^2+X(1)^2+X(2)^2 X(1)-6 X(2)
>    X(1)+X(1)+X(2)^2+X(2)\right)^2 \left(X(2)^2 X(1)^4-6 X(2) X(1)^4+X(1)^4-6 X(2)^3 X(1)^3+14 X(2)^2 X(1)^3+14 X(2)
>    X(1)^3-6 X(1)^3+X(2)^4 X(1)^2+14 X(2)^3 X(1)^2-54 X(2)^2 X(1)^2+14 X(2) X(1)^2+X(1)^2-6 X(2)^4 X(1)+14 X(2)^3
>    X(1)+14 X(2)^2 X(1)-6 X(2) X(1)+X(2)^4-6 X(2)^3+X(2)^2\right)}{X(1)^4 X(2)^4}-\frac{3 i \pi ^3 q^2 \left(X(2)
>    X(1)^2+X(1)^2+X(2)^2 X(1)-6 X(2) X(1)+X(1)+X(2)^2+X(2)\right) \left(X(2)^4 X(1)^8-11 X(2)^3 X(1)^8+40 X(2)^2
>    X(1)^8-11 X(2) X(1)^8+X(1)^8-11 X(2)^5 X(1)^7+116 X(2)^4 X(1)^7-197 X(2)^3 X(1)^7-197 X(2)^2 X(1)^7+116 X(2)
>    X(1)^7-11 X(1)^7+40 X(2)^6 X(1)^6-197 X(2)^5 X(1)^6-344 X(2)^4 X(1)^6+1706 X(2)^3 X(1)^6-344 X(2)^2 X(1)^6-197
>    X(2) X(1)^6+40 X(1)^6-11 X(2)^7 X(1)^5-197 X(2)^6 X(1)^5+1706 X(2)^5 X(1)^5-2238 X(2)^4 X(1)^5-2238 X(2)^3
>    X(1)^5+1706 X(2)^2 X(1)^5-197 X(2) X(1)^5-11 X(1)^5+X(2)^8 X(1)^4+116 X(2)^7 X(1)^4-344 X(2)^6 X(1)^4-2238 X(2)^5
>    X(1)^4+6810 X(2)^4 X(1)^4-2238 X(2)^3 X(1)^4-344 X(2)^2 X(1)^4+116 X(2) X(1)^4+X(1)^4-11 X(2)^8 X(1)^3-197 X(2)^7
>    X(1)^3+1706 X(2)^6 X(1)^3-2238 X(2)^5 X(1)^3-2238 X(2)^4 X(1)^3+1706 X(2)^3 X(1)^3-197 X(2)^2 X(1)^3-11 X(2)
>    X(1)^3+40 X(2)^8 X(1)^2-197 X(2)^7 X(1)^2-344 X(2)^6 X(1)^2+1706 X(2)^5 X(1)^2-344 X(2)^4 X(1)^2-197 X(2)^3
>    X(1)^2+40 X(2)^2 X(1)^2-11 X(2)^8 X(1)+116 X(2)^7 X(1)-197 X(2)^6 X(1)-197 X(2)^5 X(1)+116 X(2)^4 X(1)-11 X(2)^3
>    X(1)+X(2)^8-11 X(2)^7+40 X(2)^6-11 X(2)^5+X(2)^4\right)}{X(1)^5 X(2)^5}+O\left(q^3\right)$